# Filling out a new instance of a class, is this the only way (constructor injection)

Tags: c#, php, constructor

I have a class of Person

```
class Person
{
    public $Name;
    public $Age;
}
```

If I want to create a new Person and fill in his properties, I usually implement a construct and use that to fill the instance in.

```
class Person
{
    public $Name;
    public $Age;

    function __Construct( $params )
    {
        $this->Name = ( isset( $params[ "Name" ] ) ) ? $params[ "Name" ] : null;
        $this->Age = ( isset( $params[ "Age" ] ) ) ? $params[ "Age" ] : null;
    }
}

$person = new Person( array(
    "Name" => "Michael",
    "Age" => "25"
) );
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

For example, getters and setters in C#?

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

new Person { 
    Name = "Michael", 
    Age = 25 
}
```

The idea of knowing is to extend my knowledge. I am aware of magic methods but I really would like to see an example of exactly what I have represented as I get quite confused.

**EDIT://**

Here is another example that clarifies why getters and setters are very much invited into PHP.

```
<?php
abstract class DataIdentity
{
    public $Id; 
}

abstract class Animal extends DataIdentity
{
    public $Type;
    public $Size;
}

class Dog extends Animal
{
    private $BarkVolume;

    public function __Construct( $params )
    {
        $this->Type = "Dog";
        $this->Size = ( isset( $params[ "Size" ] ) ) ? $params[ "Size" ] : null;
        $this->Energy = ( isset( $params[ "Energy" ] ) ) ? $params[ "Energy" ] : null;
    }

    public function GetBarkVolume()
    {
        return $this->Energy * $this->Size;
    }
}

$animals = array(
    new Dog( array(
        "Size" => 34,
        "Energy" => 12
    ) )
);
?>
```

Without them, I must reference all properties across 3 entities in the dog constructor, then do the same in another type of class... I'm aware of other work arounds but the point still remains, this has been a big learn for me. Thanks etc.

Comment: As your properties are public, you can set them directly one you've instantiated the class: `$person = new Person(); $person->$Name='Mark Baker';` but I believe PHP5.5 introduced C#-style getters/setters

Comment: Yes that's a nice way, although I was a little worried it felt a bit noob, maybe there was a better way you know? Is this then quite common practice

Comment: Personally, I prefer protected properties, and using getters/setters because that allows any validation logic (such as checking name is a string value, etc... and I'll allow argument passing to the constructor as optional

Comment: so I understand that you can have a public method that serves the private or protected properties of the class.. but how do the getters and setters work in php?

Comment: Nope, looks like C# getters/setters are still a work-in-progress - https://wiki.php.net/rfc/propertygetsetsyntax

Comment: I use public methods such as getName()/setName() and getAge()/setAge() to work with the protected property... though for age I'd probably store dateOfBirth and provide only a getAge() method that calculated the age from the DoB property

Comment: @MarkBaker - This is helpful, i'm not fond of having methods dynamically generated regardless of them existing, if I have understood it right, it looks like the constructor or new declaration to explicit value setting is the only option which is fine. Very helpful

Comment: `return $this->BarkVolume * $this->Size;` but you'd probably also put public getters/setters in Animal for getType() and getSize() which are callable for all instances of Dog, but also for all instances of Cat that also extends Animal